# Django user homepage: typing any characters into URL displays the currently logged in user's homepage?

Tags: python, django

Just started learning Django and creating my first site. Everything is working correctly, users can be created, logged in, and logged out, but an unusual issue is occurring and I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting.

After logging in, the url redirects to /home/%username%/. This works. However, I am able to remove the %username% of the current user, input any combination of strings, and still be directed to the user's homepage.

Can someone explain why this is and how to ensure the URL throws a 404 error if it is not /home/%currentlyloggedinusername%/ or another site in urls.py? Here is my code:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views
from . import views_accounts

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/', views.index, name='index'),

    url(r'^home/share/(?P<event_id>[0-9]+)', views.share, name='share'),
    url(r'^home/(?P<username>[-\w]+)', views.home, name='home'),

    url(r'^accounts/logout', views_accounts.logout_view, name='logout_view'),
    url(r'^accounts/create_account', views_accounts.create_account, name='create_account'),
    url(r'^accounts/login', views_accounts.user_login, name='login'), ]
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

@csrf_exempt
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def home(request, username):
#   GET Meetup Event Info from all meetups the user
#   has RSVP'd to and load JSON data into variable
   # user = User.objects.get(username=username)

    user = request.user.username

    meetup_data = get_meetup_events(user)

#   Load HTML template with Meetup data
    context = {'meetup_data': meetup_data}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

user_login.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/home/%s/' % username)
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Thanks!!

EDIT:

home.html:

```js
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block main %}
<main class="container">

<!-- Create account navigation buttons to logout, log in to Facebook and Twitter, and Sync Meetup Data -->
  <div class="social-buttons">
 <a class="btn" href="#!">Import Meetup Events</a>
 <a class="btn" href="{% url 'logout_view' %}">Logout</a>
 <a class="btn" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Facebook</a>
 <a class="btn" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'twitter' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Twitter</a>
  </div>

<!-- Create a card for each Meetup the user has RSVP'd to that displays the Meetup Group Name, the Event Name, a link to the event, and a link to post the event to Twitter -->
  {% for items in meetup_data %}
 <div class="card">
   <div class="card-content">
  <span class="card-title"> {{ items.group_name }} </span>
  <img class="right" src="{{items.thumb_link}}" alt="">
  <p>{{ items.event_name }}<br><br>
    <a href="{{ items.web_link }}">Event Details</a>
  </p>
   </div>
   <div class="card-action">
  <a class="twitter-post" href="{%url 'share' items.event_id %}">
    <span >Post To Twitter</span>
  </a>
   </div>
 </div>
  {% endfor %}

</main>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please show the `home.html` template.

Comment: Note that it's a good idea to end your regexes with a dollar, e.g. `^index/$`, otherwise they will match other urls like `/index/some-other-stuff` as well.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use `csrf_exempt`, you are making your users vulnerable to CSRF attacks.

Comment: Added home.html to the post.

I am using csrf_exempt only for development - my tokens kept throwing errors and instead of wasting time troubleshooting that I skipped it for now to continue development and will come back later to fix it.

Thanks for the $ heads up, will do a bit of research and add those back in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're ignoring the username passed in the URL - you commented out the line where it uses it in the query - and you're getting it directly from `request.user` instead.

Note that this is the correct thing to do, because you don't want people accessing other users' home pages; so you should remove the username from the URL.

Comment: Uncommenting the line I commented out and commenting out the request.user portion prevents random queries from working, but still allows me to user other user's usernames that are stored in the database to access the home page.

Removing the username regex from URLs and the username argument still leaves the same problem: any string will take me to the logged in user's homepage.

How would I use the username in the URL safely?

Comment: But why does the second case matter? If you're always showing the logged-in user's data, it makes no difference what the string in the URL is. Note that adding the $ as Alasdair recommends will prevent them from adding any string at all after /home/.

Comment: Fair enough, now that I think about it, when I see the username in the URL on other websites it is typically a public profile. Which would make a lot of sense in this context. I suppose for the private profile, there really is no reason to include it in the URL! Appreciate the tips